# What is the default behaviour of git merge in respect to the --rerere-autoupdate option?

Tags: git

The documentation for git merge explains the two available option --no-rerere-autoupdate and --rerere-autoupdate as follows:

> --rerere-autoupdate
> --no-rerere-autoupdate
>
> After the rerere mechanism reuses a recorded resolution on the current conflict to update the files in the working tree, allow it to also update the index with the result of resolution. --no-rerere-autoupdate is a good way to double-check what rerere did and catch potential mismerges, before committing the result to the index with a separate git add.

So what is the default behaviour if nothing is specified?
Is it --no-rerere-autoupdate or is it --rerere-autoupdate?
Can it be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git config rerere.autoUpdate true
```

Defaults to false.

See [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-rerereautoUpdate).

Comment: Thanks.
It would be helpful IMO, if the documentation for the commands that use this command-line option like git-merge, git-am, git-revert and git-cherry-pick would reference the configuration option. At least the documentation for git-rerere should.